# Do ip addresses change location?

Tags: ip-address

I've been asked to assign a country to a set of ip addresses associated with customer transactions going back a couple of years.

Knowing that ip addresses are not fixed for a person obviously that ip address has to 'go' somewhere else. Looking a year or so on, is there any reason to believe this will return the correct country? If not, how far could it have gone?

If I logged in the UK two years ago could looking up the country associated with this ip address now return France or Ireland.

Rather round about way of asking **are IP addresses fixed to a particular country or could they switch in time?**

Answer (score 1):

IP Addresses are not linked indefinitely to a particular physical machine.
They can be traded and sold. Meaning they can be reallocated : one IP locating a server in the UK could be re-used for the end-user of an ISP in France.

But the allocation is somewhat regional (see [the Regional Internet Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry)), so an IP allocated in Europe tend to stay in Europe.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how often this happens? i.e if I go back 1 month is it likely the ip addresses have been traded? 6 months? 12 months? Just trying to get an idea of what time scales to go back with. Thanks for the answer so far.